# JS - Center Image inside canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm scaling the image down so it fits inside the canvas, the thing I am struggling to do is to then center it inside of the canavas element, does anyone know how this could be done please? Any help would be appreciated

https://jsfiddle.net/n7xL5c37/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var image = new Image();
    image.src = 'http://placehold.it/300x550';
    image.onload = function () {
        var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var wrh = image.width / image.height;
        var newWidth = canvas.width;
        var newHeight = newWidth / wrh;
        if (newHeight > canvas.height) {
                    newHeight = canvas.height;
            newWidth = newHeight * wrh;
        }

        canvasContext.drawImage(image,0,0, newWidth , newHeight);
      };
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```js
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = 'http://placehold.it/300x550';
    image.onload = function () {
        var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var wrh = image.width / image.height;
        var newWidth = canvas.width;
        var newHeight = newWidth / wrh;
        if (newHeight > canvas.height) {
     newHeight = canvas.height;
         newWidth = newHeight * wrh;
       }
        var xOffset = newWidth < canvas.width ? ((canvas.width - newWidth) / 2) : 0;
        var yOffset = newHeight < canvas.height ? ((canvas.height - newHeight) / 2) : 0;

       canvasContext.drawImage(image, xOffset, yOffset, newWidth, newHeight);
      };
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid black" />
```

Answer (score 7):

A solution that will work for both horizontal and vertical.

First find the scale which is the min scale to fit the width or height

```
var scale = Math.min(canvas.width / img.width, canvas.height / img.height);
```

Use that scale to get the img width and height

```
var w = img.width * scale;
var h = img.height * scale;
```

Then use that scale to calculate the top left as half the dist from the center

```
var left = canvas.width / 2 - w / 2;
var top = canvas.height / 2 - h / 2;
```

Answer (score 5):

Solution of Passersby works fine if you want something similar to `object-fit: contain`

This solution works fine if you want `object-fit: cover`

```
const fitImageToCanvas = (image,canvas) => {
  const canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const ratio = image.width / image.height;
  let newWidth = canvas.width;
  let newHeight = newWidth / ratio;
  if (newHeight < canvas.height) {
    newHeight = canvas.height;
    newWidth = newHeight * ratio;
  }
  const xOffset = newWidth > canvas.width ? (canvas.width - newWidth) / 2 : 0;
  const yOffset =
    newHeight > canvas.height ? (canvas.height - newHeight) / 2 : 0;
  canvasContext.drawImage(image, xOffset, yOffset, newWidth, newHeight);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of javascript photo editor download section code, you can understand with this example, in `main.js` file

```
let viewImage = document.querySelector(".view img");

savBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = viewImage.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = viewImage.naturalHeight;

    ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    ctx.drawImage(
        viewImage,
        -canvas.width / 2,
        -canvas.height / 2,
        canvas.width,
        canvas.height,
    );

    let link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = `edited.jpg`;
    link.href = canvas.toDataURL();
    link.click();
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can get the element like:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('digitalrain').getContext('2d');
```

and set x and y of your image like:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, width/2-img.width/2, height/2-img.height/2);
```